# Windows Identity Foundation + WCF (Federated scenario)

Tags: c#, wcf, wif

I've investigated for a while how to use such combimation as IdP (ADFS 2.0), AuP (custom) and WCF service (custom). Passive scenario (for ASP.NET) is set up and it works well.

The problem is that direct FederationMetadata.xml linking does not provide working application and generates to much of code and bindings in order to understand it. It's understandable how to "live" with test STS'es but configuring the real one becomes a tedious task and almost impossible mission.

1. There is FederationScenario-VS2010 example in WIF 4.0 SDK. It works well with provided testing IdP. Is there a step by steb guide on how to manualy configure relation of this sample AUP and ADFS 2.0 installation?
2. I also know about WIF Training Kit but unfortunately I even could not configure manualy Such sample as "Ex2-OnlineSTS" to use my own STS.

Could anybody provide me with such step by step tutorials for this active federated scenario?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "Active" sample in the [Claims Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's outdated. I got it work after a few days. But will mark it as correct, I hope there are some useful tutorials.